# Node JS with Java REST Api

Tags: java, node.js

is it possible to have node js interact (get & post) with Java REST Api? Can I get a sample code on how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer to the first question is yes, the answer to the second question is not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Node.js can perform RESTful API requests to many API servers, including API servers written in Java. For example:

```
var http = require('http');

http.get({'host': 'api.ipify.org', 'port': 80, 'path': '/'}, function(resp) {
    resp.on('data', function(ip) {
    console.log("My public IP address is: " + ip);
    });
});
```

Will return your public IP address from ipify's API server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can, RESTful API is using the HTTP anyways, so you can just using the `request`[1] module from NPM and act like your Node app is an HTTP client and calling your Java API

[1] https://www.npmjs.com/package/request